# I need to apply actions (a series of repetitive steps) to Gimp, but can't find how to do it

Tags: gimp, photoshop-scripting, actions, plugin

I have an xcf file that is comprised of a series of layers

The first layer, called "background" holds an image that will be manipulated by the script.
The other layers named 1,2,3,4 etc all hold masks that will be used to manipulate the background.

The first step is to duplicate the "background" layer and rename the copy to "current"
The next step is to go to a layer (lets say 1 for example) and select an area based upon colour.
The next step is to go the the "current" layer, using the selection and run a command (lets say  Filters-->Decor-->Add Bevel) with specific parameters.
I would do this for a series of steps, finally renaming the "current" layer and exporting it as a png, before deleting the current layer and starting with the next mask layer (2 in this case)

I am encountering a series of issues.

(1) I am running Gimp 2.10.32 on Ubuntu 22.10 and all the documentation/examples I am finding refer to "gimp-fu" which does not install/is deprecated.
(2) I want to learn how to write scripts/macros but all the help/docs seem to point to programming for Gimp itself.

Can I get a link to a beginners document on how to write a plugin on Gimp without gimp-fu for the environment I am in?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can write plugins for GIMP in Python.  Sorry, I'm not a coder, so I can't give you any help with coding.

Comment: Also, the other language GIMP can use is called Scheme/Script-fu. You can read more about it here: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial.html - again I can't give you much more advice. Sorry.

Comment: Gimp-fu and Python-fu are two different things, the first one is based on Scheme/Lisp and the other is Python. What is deprecated (by your distro, not by Gimp) is the Python support (but in can be reinstated, see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Heal-Selection-Missing-from-Gimp-on-Ubuntu-20-04?pid=18351#pid18351).